# Facebook App Center Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-center

We have an facebook game, it was being displayed in the facebook appcenter but recently it gives an error message

> Sorry, the details for x cannot be displayed because the app
>   is misconfigured.

I could not see any warnings or errors in the dashboard. I'm aware that the statement is not detailed but I'm not really sure what else I should tell you.

Do you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Thanks